# How to run a flask application?

Tags: python, flask

I want to know the correct way to start a flask application.  The docs show two different commands:

```
$ flask -a sample run
```

and

```
$ python3.4 sample.py
```

produce the same result and run the application correctly.

What is the difference between the two and which should be used to run a Flask application?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

The `flask` command is a CLI for interacting with Flask apps. The [docs](http://flask.palletsprojects.com/cli/) describe how to use CLI commands and add custom commands. The `flask run` command is the preferred way to start the development server.

Never use this command to deploy publicly, use a production WSGI server such as Gunicorn, uWSGI, Waitress, or mod_wsgi.

As of Flask 2.2, use the `--app` option to point the command at your app. It can point to an import name or file name. It will automatically detect an app instance or an app factory called `create_app`. Use the `--debug` option to run in debug mode with the debugger and reloader.

```
$ flask --app sample --debug run
```

---

Prior to Flask 2.2, the `FLASK_APP` and `FLASK_ENV=development` environment variables were used instead. `FLASK_APP` and `FLASK_DEBUG=1` can still be used in place of the CLI options above.

```
$ export FLASK_APP=sample
$ export FLASK_ENV=development
$ flask run
```

On Windows CMD, use `set` instead of `export`.

```
> set FLASK_APP=sample
```

For PowerShell, use `$env:`.

```
> $env:FLASK_APP = "sample"
```

---

The `python sample.py` command runs a Python file and sets `__name__ == "__main__"`. If the main block calls `app.run()`, it will run the development server. If you use an app factory, you could also instantiate an app instance at this point.

```py
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = create_app()
    app.run(debug=True)
```

---

Both these commands ultimately start the Werkzeug [development server](http://flask.palletsprojects.com/server/), which as the name implies starts a simple HTTP server that should only be used during development. You should prefer using the `flask run` command over the `app.run()`.

Answer (score 42):

[Latest documentation](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/cli/) has the following example assuming you want to run `hello.py`(using `.py` file extension is optional):

Unix, Linux, macOS, etc.:

```
$ export FLASK_APP=hello
$ flask run
```

Windows:

```
> set FLASK_APP=hello
> flask run
```

Answer (score 27):

you just need to run this command

**python app.py**

(app.py is your desire flask file)

but make sure your .py file has the following flask settings(related to port and host)

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api
import sys
import os

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
port = 5100

if sys.argv.__len__() > 1:
    port = sys.argv[1]
print("Api running on port : {} ".format(port))

class topic_tags(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return {'hello': 'world world'}

api.add_resource(topic_tags, '/')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=port)
```

Comment: port=1234 param not working any more by now for app.run()

Answer (score 5):

The very simples automatic way without exporting anything is using `python app.py` see the example here

```py
from flask import (
    Flask, 
    jsonify
)

# Function that create the app 
def create_app(test_config=None ):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__)

    # Simple route
    @app.route('/')
    def hello_world(): 
        return jsonify({
           "status": "success",
            "message": "Hello World!"
        }) 
     
    return app # do not forget to return the app

APP = create_app()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # APP.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5000, debug=True)
    APP.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also run a flask application this way while being explicit about activating the DEBUG mode.

```
FLASK_APP=app.py FLASK_DEBUG=true flask run
```

Comment: great answer. for the unfortunate windows users, like me, it would be:
set FLASK_APP=myFlaskScript.py && set FLASK_DEBUG=true && flask run

Answer (score 0):

For Linux/Unix/MacOS :-

```
export FLASK_APP = sample.py
flask run
```

For Windows :-

```
python sample.py
      OR
set FLASK_APP = sample.py
flask run
```

Answer (score 0):

For pycharm or VS Code editor in windows run these line on the terminal:

```
set FLASK_APP=main.py
$env:FLASK_APP = "main.py"
flask run
```