# Attribute Error: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app' while running Flask

Tags: python, flask, attributeerror, apscheduler

I am trying to trigger my flask code to run as a scheduled job in intervals of few minutes. The application mainly does Webscraping of news from multiple sites and displays it as a HTML Webpage.

When I schedule my Flask function using *apscheduler*, I start getting the below error:

```
Job "news_page (trigger: interval[0:02:00], next run at: 2020-03-11 17:54:32 IST)" raised an exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\poudupa\PycharmProjects\SecNews\venv\lib\site-packages\apscheduler\executors\base.py", line 125, in run_job
retval = job.func(*job.args, **job.kwargs)
File "C:\Users\poudupa\PycharmProjects\SecNews\venv\Scripts\try_flask.py", line 20, in news_page
return render_template('news_screen.html', hackernews = hackernews, bcnews = bcnews, tpnews = tpnews, nsnews = nsnews, drnews = drnews, wsnews = wsnews)
File "C:\Users\poudupa\PycharmProjects\SecNews\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\templating.py", line 136, in render_template
ctx.app.update_template_context(context)
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'app'
```

Here is my Flask code:

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
from pullnews import *
from apscheduler.schedulers.background import BackgroundScheduler
import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)
app.debug=True

class Item:
    def __init__(self, vals):
        self.__dict__ = vals

@app.route('/')
def news_page():
    hackernews = get_hackernews()
    bcnews = get_bcnews()
    tpnews = get_threatpost()
    nsnews = get_nakedsecurity()
    drnews = get_darkreading()
    wsnews = get_welivesecurity()
    return render_template('news_screen.html', hackernews = hackernews, bcnews = bcnews, tpnews = tpnews, nsnews = nsnews, drnews = drnews, wsnews = wsnews)

sched = BackgroundScheduler(daemon=True)
sched.add_job(news_page, 'interval', minutes=2)
sched.start()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

How do I resolve this error? This does not occur when I manually run the Flask code without the scheduler job.

Comment: why are you rendering a template in a background process? How will this actually render to a browser? Does your `news_page` function need to be split into 2? One to get the latest news data on a schedule, and a flask route to display that latest news?

Comment: @Jon: So you mean I need to have two functions, one for just getting the data and the other one just for rendering? Could you help me with a pseudo code here? Thanks!

Comment: Maybe...? Can you clearly state what you want to do with the background process? If you are just trying to run the app, which will make it possible to call your news_page function via the root route then check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882642/how-to-run-a-flask-application.