# unable to use getCurrentPosition() in a Flask local host app

Tags: javascript, flask, geolocation

I'm working on a python flask app for practice. I want to access the getCurrentPosition() of JS to get the geolocation. However, as the app is running on http://localhost:5000/ I'm getting an error that **getCurrentPosition() and watchPosition() are deprecated on insecure origins**.

Is there a way that it will work on the flask localhost server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the resolution. Geolocation can only be used in HTTPS requests.
In order to convert your localhost flask app to HTTPS from HTTP, you have to use OpenSSL to create a key and certificate.

Follow the below step to set up your HTTPS environment for the flask localhost server

- If you have installed Git then OpenSSL command comes in a package. Open git bash where you want to store the files.
- Run the below command in Git Bash.

`openssl req -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -x509 -days 365 -out certificate.pem`

- Change your app.run() method in python script to below

```
context = (r"{path}\certificate.pem", r"{path}\key.pem")
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0',port=5000,debug=True,ssl_context=context)
```

path refers to the location directory where the key and certificate files are stored.

Answer (score 0):

Something that tripped me up is that documentation rarely seems to mention `app.run()` anymore. You can also set up your key and certificate using flask CLI. Check `flask run --help` for more information.

This post explains the difference between the two methods you can use to run flask: [How to run a flask application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882642/how-to-run-a-flask-application)

Edit:
I also need to add that a self-generated key and certificate will not be recognized as safe by the browsers and as a result, Chrome will not allow location sharing. You can obtain a certificate online, or in my case, use a different browser to test (Safari worked great).