Do I need "if __name__ == '__main__': app.run()" in my Flask app on WSGI server?
I'm deploying a Flask application to an WSGI server. In my development code, I have the typical if __name__ == '__main__': app.run() block to run the app locally.  I'm unsure if this code snippet is necessary when using an WSGI server.
Is the if __name__ == '__main__': app.run() block required for deployment on an WSGI server?
How does the WSGI server interact with my Flask application if not through app.run()?
I've reviewed the Flask deployment documentation, but I'd appreciate clarification specifically regarding WSGI servers.
The flask run command seems to be starting your Flask application without the if __name__ == '__main__': app.run() block, while directly running python app.py doesn't. This suggests there might be an alternative entry point defined elsewhere.

No you don't need the __name__ == "__main__ ... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29882642/how-to-run-a-flask-application and per the Docs you can read "The only required argument to Gunicorn tells it how to load your Flask application. " ... so Gunicorn loads flask (and I assume its similar for other wsgi server). See further: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/deploying/

This is what we have in the Docs for uWSGI: "If you’re using the app factory pattern, you’ll need to create a small Python file to create the app, then point uWSGI at that." - so this little file "wsgi.py" is the piece that handles creating your app. Again, see further:  See further: https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.2.x/deploying/

Issue
In deployment need if __name__ == '__main__': app.run() this block in flask app.
Solution
When deploying a Flask application to a WSGI server, the if name == 'main': app.run() block is not required. This block is used to run the Flask development server when you execute your script directly with Python app.py. However, in a production environment with a WSGI server, the server itself calls the application’s callable object (which is usually the Flask app instance) to handle requests.
Alternate Entry Points
Different servers have different entry points for the Flask app but they are somewhat the same refer docs for more servers like:

Gunicorn
Waitress
mod_wsgi
uWSGI
gevent
eventlet
ASGI

I will show with Gunicorn as it is a popular option in production mode.
from flask import Flask
app = app = Flask(__name__)
 
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello World


gunicorn -w 4 'hello:app'

